# Sub Menu - Positioning is wrong in some browser's

Tags: html, css

i write an own wordpress theme at the moment and have a problem with the submenu. I want that the submenu appears after hovering over the "Events" link in the example below. In some browser's the submenu is displayed under the "Events" link, with a 5px margin to the left. This is fine. In other browsers (Firefox 17 on Win 7) the submenu is displayed on the right side from the "Events" link and not under the "Events" text like it should be.

Does somebody know why this happens and how i can get rid of it?

Thanks.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqAIy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is this part of your code that you need to change:

```
.menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
}
```

To this:

```
.menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
}
```

(so inline-block to block)
Tested and working in IE9+, Mz FF, Chrome & Safari

Answer (score 0):

Now add this code

```
nav .menu li {
position:relative;
}

nav .menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    display:block;
        left:0;right:0;top:18px;
        position: absolute;
}
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mGoBe)**

This code is **universal Run all Latest and Standard Browser**